# Is any Gaussian measure on a separable Hilbert space a probability measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\mu$ be a measure on $(H,\mathscr{B}(H))$. $\mathscr{B}(H)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field.

We say $\mu$ is Gaussian if $H\ni z\mapsto \langle x,z\rangle_H$ is Gaussian for all $x \in H$.

Question: Is $\mu$ actually a probability measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\mu(H) = \mu( z: \langle x,z \rangle \in \mathbb{R})=1$ by gaussianity of $z \mapsto \langle x,z \rangle$.